# Why is my algorithm not generating the new content I want?

Tags: knowledge, wordplay, pattern

I've seen how good neural networks and large language models can be at generating content based on textual input, so I asked someone to make me an algorithm to do that... My instructions were quite clear, but it's been less than successful.

If I describe my inputs and outputs, maybe you can figure out what instructions I gave for what the algorithm should do?

I input a britpop/indie rock band and got a British prime minister.

I tried another British rock band, and just got the sound of a dog barking.

Inspired by the last band's name, I tried something else from Greek mythology and just got some sepia photos made by children, clearly they faked these!

Thinking I needed a more general input, I used a whole music genre. I thought the output might have shared that genre's teen spirit, but it wasn't a TV show set in a school... The algorithm gave me a father and son both executive producers for music labels. Maybe I was getting closer, but I'd had enough of music...

Giving up on music, I tried to put a Scottish poet into the algorithm, but again I just got some children out, at least this time they were still Scottish!

Looking for an American author to input, I sent it into the algorithm and just got some links back.

The only successful input was when I put in someone from the NFL and got out one of the authors of Good Omens.

What were my instructions for making this algorithm, and why isn't it working?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You asked for an algorithm to

> replace you with AI; instead the programme replaces U with AI

Thus when you asked about the indy band

> [BLUR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blur_(band)) you got [BLAIR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Blair)

... when you asked about the other band

> [MUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muse_(band)) you got [MAISE](https://eeggs.com/items/43039.html) (thanks Revolver_Ocelot for the detective work for this one)

... when you asked about the Greek myths

> [FURIES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erinyes) you got [FAIRIES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cottingley_Fairies)

... when you asked about the music genre

> [GRUNGE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grunge) you did not get [GRANGE Hill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grange_Hill), but [GRAINGE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucian_Grainge) and [GRAINGE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nigel_Grainge)

...when you asked about the poet

> [BURNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Burns) you got [BAIRNS](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bairn#English)

... when you asked about the author

> [CHUN](https://www.yechunauthor.com/) you got CHAIN

... when you asked about the NFL

> [GUMAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mike_Guman) you got [GAIMAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neil_Gaiman)

It's not working because

> AI should not replace U; what might be meant as a PUN is a PAIN.

Comment: (Rot13: Qba'g sbetrg gur frpbaq onaq'f anzr vf fbzrguvat sebz Terrx zlgubybtl.)

Comment: I think that the missing band name is (Rot13: ZHFR, naq fbhaq bs qbex onexvat vf ZNVFR, n qbt perqvgrq va Oebxra ol Avar Vapu Anvyf sbe "onexf naq ebnef")

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot Thanks! I'll add this to the answer.

Comment: That's all of them! I've bountied one of your answers @Revolver_Ocelot as a thank you for helping Daniel